Conditional expectation - alternative expression
Consider the following set-up.
$F:[0,\omega]\rightarrow[0,1]$ where $X$ is a real-valued random variable.
The conditional expectation of $X$ given $X<x$ is:
$E(X|X<x)=\frac{1}{F(x)} \int_0^s tf(t)dt$. Denote this equation (1)
Via the integration by parts, for $F(x)E(X|X<x)$, we obtain
$F(x)E(X|X<x)=\int_0^x tf(t)dt=xF(x)-\int_0^x F(t)dt$. Denote this equation (2)
My questions are:

How do we derive (1) from the traditional conditional expectation definition?

How do we derive (2) via the integration by parts?



Your formulas need work, they seem incorrect. What is $\omega$? What is $s$? What is the relationship between $X$ and $F$?


Consider the following set-up. $F:[0,ω]→[0,1]$
where $X$ is a real-valued random variable.

Assuming $F$ is the Cumulative Distribution Function of random variable  $X$ and $f$ is the probability density function so: $$f(x)=\dfrac{\mathrm d F(x)}{\mathrm d x}$$


How do we derive (1) from the traditional conditional expectation definition?


The definition of conditional expectation with respect to an event is: $$\mathsf E(X\mid A) = \dfrac{\mathsf E(X\,\mathbf 1_A)}{\mathsf P(A)}$$
When the event is $\{X\leqslant x\}$ then :$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X\mid X\leqslant x) &= \dfrac{\mathsf E(X\,\mathbf 1_{X\leqslant x})}{\mathsf P(X\leqslant x)}\\[1ex] &= \dfrac{\displaystyle\int_{0}^x t f(t)\,\mathrm dt}{F(x)}\end{align}$$
$\displaystyle\therefore\quad F(x)\,\mathsf E(X\mid X\leqslant x) = \int_0^x t f(t)\,\mathrm d t$


How do we derive (2) via the integration by parts?


Let $u=t$ and $v=F(t)$, then:
$$\begin{align} \int u\,\mathrm d v &= uv-\int v\,\mathrm d u&&\small\text{indefinite integration by parts}\\[2ex]\int_0^x t f(t) \,\mathrm d x &= \int_0^{F(x)} t\,\mathrm d F(t) &&\small\text{definite integration} \\[1ex] &= [t\,F(t)]_{t=0}^{t=x} - \int_0^x F(t)\,\mathrm d t\\[1ex] &= x\,F(x) - \int_0^x F(t)\,\mathrm d t\end{align}$$

thanks a lot! this makes sense.
